# How do you temporarily pause a loop until a button is pressed in java

Tags: loops, button

How can I make a loop temporarily pause while i wait for a button to be pressed? Iv been looking around for a while, and I cant seem to find it, thought I would try here.

EDIT-

I am creating a blackjack game, I added a gui to it with buttons, HITME and STAND once the game gets to the point in the loop where i need to get player input to either, HITME or STAND I added buttons to execute that, but I cant figure out how to pause the loop to check and see if the button was pressed, and which one to continue.

what i have tried is this:

```
 (othercode)  
g.printPlayerCards(p1);
            g.totalworth(p1);
            thing.messagetop("Your total card amount is: " + p1.getTotalWorth());
            thing.messagetop("Hit me? or stay?");
            thing.waitonbutton();


public void waitonbutton(){
        wantingtobeclick = 1;
        do{
            while(!(hitme == 0)){
                hitme = 0;
                wantingtobeclick =0;
            }
        }while(wantingtobeclick == 1);
    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(wantingtobeclick == 1){
            if (e.getSource() == HitMe){
                hitme = 1;
                System.out.println("ICLICKEDHITME");
                g.hitMe(player1);
                waitonbutton();
            }
            if(e.getSource() == Stand){
                hitme = 1;
                g.changestandhit();
            }
        }
    }
```

It just stays in a infinite loop and doesn't continue on with the loop in main.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show some pieces of code? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: "loops" are generally only used in realtime games. If using a UI Toolkit, write code that *reacts to events* (the rules are different for a MV*M, but..). That is, do A, wait for the button, do B. (But the title is *very* confusing because it's about a button *in Java* being pressed? How does this Java and Python interact/relate?)

Comment: *React* to events. Instead of making the game driven by the loop prompting for input, make the game respond to inputs. If you do want to keep the loop-driven approach, look up "Modal Dialogs".

Comment: A simplistic approach is to just put "othercode" into a function, and call it at the end of actionPerformed

Comment: To elaborate on user224's comment on loops, your GUI framework already has a loop for dispatching events(that is how it executes actionPerformed).  So you generally wouldn't have your own loop, and instead just have everything be event driven.

Comment: If you really need to use a loop, you'll probably need to read up on thread management APIs, because you're going to have one thread that your button handlers are on, the GUI's thread, and then your loop on another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, just in case anyone else has the same issue:

i added this to main:

> ```
>         do{
>
>         } while(!(thing.waitonbutton()));
> ```

then this to my graphics class:

```
> public boolean waitonbutton(){
        wantingtobeclick = 1;
        if(hitme == 1){
            wantingtobeclick = 0;
            hitme = 0;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(wantingtobeclick == 1){
            if (e.getSource() == HitMe){
                hitme = 1;
                g.hitMe(player1);
            }
            if(e.getSource() == Stand){
                hitme = 1;
                g.changestandhit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: not having your code event-driven will drain your user's battery in no time. An infinite while loop has the cpu running all the time.

Answer (score 1):

With just an button and a few state variables you will make it with no while loop :
i made a little fiddle here : http://jsbin.com/uyetat/2/edit

The code is :

```
var elapsed=document.getElementById('timeElapsed');
var switcher = document.getElementById('switcher');

var timerStarted    = false;
var refreshInterval = null ;
var timeStarted     = 0    ;

function switchTimer() {
         if (timerStarted) {
              timerStarted = false;
              clearInterval(refreshInterval);
              switcher.value = "start";
         } else {
              timeStarted = Date.now();
              refreshInterval = setInterval (refresh, 100);
              timerStarted=true;
              switcher.value = "stop";
         }    
 }

 function refresh() {
       elapsed.value = (Date.now() - timeStarted);
 }
```

the html body is :

```
 <output id='timeElapsed' >not started
 </output>

 <button  onclick='switchTimer()' >
    <output id='switcher' >Start </output>
 </button>
```

Rq : if you prefer you can use mousedown / mouseup events and measure the hold time.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to 'pause' a loop is to execute more code during the loop, preferably on a different thread. I.e.

```
while (true) {
    if (_buttonIsPressed) {
        Thread.sleep(5000); // loop is paused
    }
}
```

But, more to the point, it feels like you might be going about things the wrong way.

Instead of running a loop to check to see if something has happened, you're better off firing an action once a button is pressed. This is called [event-driven programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming).

[image: Example of events]

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to the same question recently and as I haven't found any satisfying answer, I was able to handle it like below. Hope this will help anyone for the future running into the same problem. Please note, that I'm a beginner, so there might be a better way to handle it. That said - it does exactly what is expected - stops the loop until button is pressed. In the example below I use for loop, but it works just as well with while.

The trick is to refer to GUI, which is run in a separate thread then backend, and synchronize loop with this thread. Below is of course simplified for the purpose of example. The code displays frame with 1 button, which increases counter every click.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    var button = new JButton("loop");
    button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

    //create frame thread
    Runnable frameThread = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            var frame = new JFrame("Wait Example");
            frame.add(button);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    };

    //create action listener for button
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            synchronized (frameThread) {
                frameThread.notifyAll();
            }
        }
    });

    //run frame thread
    EventQueue.invokeLater(frameThread);

    //loop synchronized with frame thread
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        synchronized (frameThread){
            button.setText(Integer.toString(i));
            try {
                frameThread.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```